# How to (automatically) determine a visually appealing line spread?

Tags: math-mode, typography, line-spacing, setspace

I'm writing a "larger" document with a lot of mathematics. Occasionally, I use a notation like

```
p \xrightarrow{\mathcal A^X} q
```

which produces tall lines. LaTeX increases the line spread for those lines resulting in a very uneven layout where some lines have normal line spread and others don't.

I currently "solved" the problem by increasing the line spread to 1.2 using the `setspace` package. Below you find a small example how the increased line spread looks like.

[image]

It seems to be OK now, but I feel that a lline spread of 1.2 is too much. Is there a way to (automatically) determine the "smallest" line spread that prevents different line spreads in a document without a try-and-error approach? If not the "smallest", a visually more appealing line spread is of course also OK.

I searched the web and tex.stackexchange for answers but could not find a satisfactory one. I hope you can help me.

Comment: can't you use display math?

Comment: I added a small example from my text. Since I use these notation several times in the text, I feel that display math might disturb the flow even more.

Comment: You could try with `\tracingoutput1 \showboxbreadth\maxdimen \showboxdepth4 \lineskip1.42pt` and then grep the log for `\glue(\lineskip) 1.42`, adjusting the spread in a programmed loop outside the TeX process.

Comment: In my opinion, lines having different lineskip in such a dense mathematical text is not a problem. Nobody really reads the text quickly to notice this while actually reading it. And a page with so much math will hardly be really visually appealing, no matter the even or uneven lineskip. I suggest using slightly increased linespread, to value like `1.07`, so that the text is "airy" in general and a bit larger line skip than this will then be almost unnoticed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you chose exactly 1.07?

Comment: Also, if this is a typical notation you use a lot, you could consider making a special macro for it which lowers the arrow, for instance.

Comment: You can also try the command `\smash` to force the line spacing to ignore the math boxes. That's for cases when the line spacing increase is rather unnecessary.

Comment: @Dan basically a rule of thumb. 7% seem to make the lines "look spaced", but adds a minimum amount such that the ones conaining some a bit cmore complicated maths don't stand out too much. And 10% seems to look just too much spaced in longer texts with little math. This setting may vary from font to font and from eye to eye, I use CM/LM fonts.

Comment: I agree with T. Verron, it is a good idea to add `\smash` if they are used in the text, may even be a good idea to write `\xrightarrow{\scriptscriptstyle u}` instead.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I'd like to try your suggestion. What would be a good way to lower the arrow?

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with David Carlisle's comment: Reorganize the text to place the offending construction in a display. If it is complex enough that it is so high, it will benefit from the extra space/attention. And I disagree strongly with "It is only math, why bother if it is hard to read"; to the contrary, if the subject matter is hard, you owe it to the gentle reader to make his reading as confortable as possible.